Fine Tune Huggingface model via Trainer API without labels?
I am following Huggingfaces Tutorial on fine-tuning a model. Unfortunately, they only show the procedure for fine-tuning BERT to a classifier by providing labeled data.
My case is a bit different: I want to fine-tune gpt-2 to generate text in a specific writing style. So my input would be just the text (in that style) without any label. I have tried the code below but that doesn't work well and results in very bad quality that
includes many special characters.
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./results",
    overwrite_output_dir=True,
    num_train_epochs=3,
    per_device_train_batch_size=4,
    save_steps=10_000,
    save_total_limit=2,
    prediction_loss_only=True
)

data_collator = DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(
    tokenizer=gen_tokenizer,
    mlm=False,  # Suggestion from ChatGPT
)

# Initialize the Trainer
trainer = Trainer(
    model=gen_model,
    args=training_args,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    train_dataset=tokenized_dataset,
)   

trainer.train()

Is there anything I should consder/change in my code? I am grateful for any answer because I couldn't find anything online

If you want to train your model to generate new text in a style similar to that of your texts, then this is Causal Language Modeling.
There is a separate page dedicated to this topic on HuggingFace: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/en/tasks/language_modeling.
Or, if you want a complete guide, there is a beautiful article on Medium on how to fine-tune the GPT-2: https://medium.com/@prashanth.ramanathan/fine-tuning-a-pre-trained-gpt-2-model-and-performing-inference-a-hands-on-guide-57c097a3b810. The dataset is wikitext (without labels) and the code sample looks like this:
# Define training arguments
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='/mnt/disks/disk1/results',
    evaluation_strategy='epoch',
    num_train_epochs=1,
    per_device_train_batch_size=4,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=4,
    warmup_steps=500,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    logging_dir='/mnt/disks/disk1/logs'
)

# Initialize Trainer
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=tokenized_datasets['train'],
    eval_dataset=tokenized_datasets['validation'],
)


Thank you very much! :)
